# What would happens if global warming cause enough atmosphere loss?

Tags: atmosphere, climate-change

What would happens if due to increased volume and reduced density, the global warming cause consistent loss into space of certain gases of atmosphere? What would we observe?

Comment: The question kinda answers itself... increased atmospheric volume with reduced density, and consistent loss of certain gases into space (on top of the current consistent loss).

Comment: No. What would happens? Climatici changes? Difficulty to breath? Which gases are lost? In which quantities/proportions?

Comment: [Reminder to close-voters](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3773/6986): The problem cannot be solved if the OP is not made aware of it.

Comment: To answer your question it would be helpful for us to know the manner of atmospheric loss - ie. what mechanism is causing it and over what timescale. After all, gasses are being constantly lost from Earth's atmosphere now, just slowly.

Comment: You've answered your own question: assuming something is going on that isn't really happening but let's just assume it was, what would we observe? The answer is: we would see it happening. I don't get what you want to know. Don't be so insecure. Close to 100% of the questions here and most financially successful worlds can't happen. There will be no zombies, ftl, space colonization, magic, crazy religious takeovers of Britain and so on. But who cares. Building worlds is more about believability and internal logic than realism. It's a classic 19th century style idea, just do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what kind of warming we are talking about.

There is one handy chart: [chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_escape)

[image: Atmosphere gravity temperature dependence]

The Earth needs to get quite warmer before it begins to lose water. However, water molecules can dissociate, and hydrogen would readily escape into space. This process is going on throughout the Earth history, but it's quite slow. Without heating, oceans should last for at least another 5 billion years.

Eventually, due to warming caused by increased solar luminosity, Earth may lose most of its water and turn into Venus - but even if we would get to water boiling point (100C at 1 atm pressure), losing all water would take millions of years. Other gases - nitrogen, oxygen, carbon dioxide - are likely to stick around for billions of years.

Comment: True although the boiling point of water would increase as the pressure in the atmosphere built up from the boiling oceans

Answer (score 2):

Firstly this is not even a remotely likely scenario. However if the rate that gases leak from the atmosphere into space was dramatically accelerated for whatever reason, it would eventually have serious consequences. There would be less protection from cosmic rays and solar storms leading to increased rates of cancer.

The atmospheric pressure would decrease and would be able to hold less moisture which in turn would affect the climate and the amount of rain fall.

A reduced partial pressure of oxygen would have adverse consequences for all animal life, causing stress on animals that needed the most oxygen first for example animals that need to run fast. Eventually all animal life would die due to lack of oxygen and all plants as well as plants also need to respire.